# Pointer to a temporary but still works?

Tags: c++, qt

The problem with the following is that the function returns a pointer to a temporary. However it builds and runs fine here, Qt Creator on macOS.

```
const char* get_str()
{
    QByteArray arr("Some text");
    return arr.constData();
}

int main()
{
    const char *s = get_str();
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make it fail? Or is this one of those undefined behavior cases?

I think by doing `printf("%s\n", get_str());` we escape the problem, right?

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is Undefined.  One of the possible behaviours is appearing to work .... until it does not, usually during a demo to a customer.

Comment: TL;DR version: You cannot reliably make it fail.

Comment: What about the last question, am I really escaping the problem by accessing it on the same line? Or am I still on undefined behavior territory?

Comment: Still UB. `arr` is destroyed when `get_str` exits, and that's before `printf` gets its look at the returned pointer.

Comment: Your `get_str` function is guaranteed to return a dangling pointer no matter how it is called.